# How to get the last element from an associative array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have the following associative array dynamically defined in bash. ELEMENTS is unknown in advance.

```
declare -A array
for ELEM in $ELEMENTS; do
    array[$ELEM]='something'
done
```

How can I get the last value without iterating over all elements?

Comment: `echo ${array[last]}`

Comment: There's not really a proper concept of the "last" element of an associative array. Do you want the element that was most recently added?

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear. Now it is more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the last inserted index and reuse:

```
declare -A array
for ELEM in $ELEMENTS; do
    array[$ELEM]='something'
done

echo "last inserted element is: ${array[$ELEM]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
declare -A array
array[foo]='something'
array[bar]='blah'
array[last]='nothing'
echo ${array[last]}
```